# v4l2 : how can I enable software trigger?

Tags: webcam, automation, camera

I am working on jetson TX2, with a FSM-IMX304M camera and I use V4L2 API.

I would like to use software trigger, but I don't know how to use it and haven't found anything by searching.

I need to synchronize the camera with a turntable. The idea is to send x triggers every 50 ms (read-out time of the camera is around 50ms), to fill x buffers (the minimum buffer id is 3 and the maximal is 32). When the first buffer is filled, I send an other trigger to fill the second one, and during this time, the camera send the image to the jetson.

I try to implement this solution because it is consuming time to stop/start stream for each sequence (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/media/uapi/v4l/vidioc-streamon.html). If this solution is not feasible, what can I try instead?

As shown below, the command does not return trigger. I have no idea how activate it:

```
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-ctrls

Camera Controls

                 group_hold 0x009a2003 (bool)   : default=0 value=0 flags=execute-on-write
                sensor_mode 0x009a2008 (int64)  : min=0 max=3 step=1 default=0 value=0 flags=slider
                       gain 0x009a2009 (int64)  : min=0 max=480 step=1 default=0 value=0 flags=slider
                   exposure 0x009a200a (int64)  : min=28 max=1000000 step=1 default=27879 value=28 flags=slider
                 frame_rate 0x009a200b (int64)  : min=1500000 max=24000000 step=1 default=24000000 value=1500000 flags=slider
                bypass_mode 0x009a2064 (intmenu): min=0 max=1 default=0 value=0
            override_enable 0x009a2065 (intmenu): min=0 max=1 default=0 value=0
               height_align 0x009a2066 (int)    : min=1 max=16 step=1 default=1 value=1
                 size_align 0x009a2067 (intmenu): min=0 max=2 default=0 value=0
           write_isp_format 0x009a2068 (int)    : min=1 max=1 step=1 default=1 value=1
   sensor_signal_properties 0x009a2069 (u32)    : min=0 max=4294967295 step=1 default=0 [30][18] flags=read-only, has-payload
    sensor_image_properties 0x009a206a (u32)    : min=0 max=4294967295 step=1 default=0 [30][16] flags=read-only, has-payload
  sensor_control_properties 0x009a206b (u32)    : min=0 max=4294967295 step=1 default=0 [30][34] flags=read-only, has-payload
          sensor_dv_timings 0x009a206c (u32)    : min=0 max=4294967295 step=1 default=0 [30][16] flags=read-only, has-payload
           low_latency_mode 0x009a206d (bool)   : default=0 value=0
               test_pattern 0x009a206f (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=0 value=0
             operation_mode 0x009a2071 (menu)   : min=0 max=1 default=0 value=0
                black_level 0x009a2074 (int64)  : min=0 max=4095 step=1 default=0 value=0 flags=slider

check_firmware_compatibility 0x009a2075 (menu) : min=0 max=2 default=1 value=1
global_shutter_mode 0x009a207b (menu) : min=0 max=1 default=0 value=0
sensor_modes 0x009a2082 (int) : min=0 max=30 step=1 default=30 value=3 flags=read-only
timing_generator_mode 0x009a208c (menu) : min=0 max=3 default=0 value=0
expanded_exposure 0x009a2099 (int64) : min=0 max=4294967295 step=1 default=0 value=0 flags=slider
delay_frame 0x009a209a (int64) : min=0 max=4294967295 step=1 default=0 value=0 flags=slider
```

Thank you for your help.